# New-Object fails on PowerShell 2 with Constructor not found error

Tags: powershell

I have the below script running fine on PowerShell 5

```html
$NetworkChange = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.networkchange

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $NetworkChange -EventName NetworkAddressChanged -SourceIdentifier "NetworkChanged" -Action {

    Write-Host "network switched"
    $LanConnected=@(Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 2" | Where-Object {$_.netconnectionid -like "*Local Area Connection*"})

    If($LanConnected){
        Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus = 2" | Where-Object {$_.netconnectionid -like "*Wireless Network Connection*"} | ForEach-Object {$_.disable()}
    }

    Else {
        Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter | Where-Object {$_.netconnectionid -like "*Wireless Network Connection*"} | ForEach-Object {$_.enable()}
    }

}
```

However it fails on PowerShell 2 with the below error related to the New-Object cmdlet

```html
New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Net.NetworkInformation.networkchange.
At line:1 char:11
+ New-Object <<<<  System.Net.NetworkInformation.networkchange
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Any idea why it fails? Is there a different syntax for the New-Object cmdlet on PowerShell 2?

Note: Our estate is still on PowerShell 2 hence this struggle.
Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: Got it. It looks like in PowerShell 2 I have to directly pass the type to the object reference of Register-ObjectEvent. So the first 2 lines would be $NetworkChange = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.networkchange]

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $NetworkChange -EventName NetworkAddressChanged -SourceIdentifier "NetworkChanged" -Action {

Answer (score 0):

In PS5 works this code:

```
$NetworkChange = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange]::new()
```

PS2 says `[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange] doesn't contain a method named 'new'.` So we can go around it by creating a variable 'classic' way:

```
New-Variable -Name NetworkChange -Value ([System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange])
$NetworkChange
```